# Strings with WPML and Wordpress

Tags: string, wordpress, wpml

I have a really impossible task for me. I know how put string content in wordpress (  )

but i don't know how put in this code. I want delete call and show text string.

```
if (!is_page_template('splash.php')) {
    echo '<!-- _________________________ Start Custom HTML _________________________ -->' . 
    '<div class="header_html">' . "\n" . 
        '<div class="header_html_outer">' . "\n" .
            '<div class="header_html_inner">' . "\n";
                if ($cmsms_option[CMSMS_SHORTNAME . '_header_custom_html']) {
                    echo stripslashes($cmsms_option[CMSMS_SHORTNAME . '_header_html']) . "\n";
                }
                echo '<div class="cl"></div>' . 
            '</div>' . "\n" . 
        '</div>' . "\n" . 
    '</div>' . "\n" . 
    '<!-- _________________________ Finish Custom HTML _________________________ -->';
}
```

i can change it with the nexxt code, but show in front : _e( "text i want translate", "comercialdelmotor");

```
if (!is_page_template('splash.php')) {
    echo '<!-- _________________________ Start Custom HTML _________________________ -->' . 
    '<div class="header_html">' . "\n" . 
        '<div class="header_html_outer">' . "\n" .
            '<div class="header_html_inner">' . "\n" . '_e( "text i want translate", "comercialdelmotor");';
                echo '<div class="cl"></div>' . 
            '</div>' . "\n" . 
        '</div>' . "\n" . 
    '</div>' . "\n" . 
    '<!-- _________________________ Finish Custom HTML _________________________ -->';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You are correct in using `_e()` to echo a string. Your syntax use is wrong though. Never ever use `"` to enclose a translatable string, the translator does not recognise it, so your string is skipped/ignored.

The correct way is to use `'`. So your string should look something like this `_e( 'string to be translated',  'domainname' );` Note that `domainname` is optional, so using `_e( 'string to be translated' );` is also correct.

You can go and read more about translating your theme in this great tutorial. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/translating-your-theme--wp-25014

Comment: i put that code but show in front this: _e( "text i want translate", "comercialdelmotor");

Comment: You have a slight syntax issue, change `'<div class="header_html_inner">' . "\n" . '_e( "text i want translate", "comercialdelmotor");';` to `'<div class="header_html_inner">' . "\n" . _e( 'text i want translate', 'comercialdelmotor');`. And as I said in my answer, NEVER EVER USE `"` IN A TRANSLATABLE STRING